# Cell phone questions in two separate countries are considered duplicates

Tags: discussion, support, duplicates

I posted a question about using cell phones in Japan and now want to post the exact same question except being for South Korea. It is regarded as a duplicate. So how do I go about getting answers to these two things? Should I put it in one question or try to reformulate?

Comment: Regarded as a duplicate by the site or by some user or moderator? What exactly are you seeing when you try to post this question?

Comment: One thing, be careful you didn't accidentally paste the exact same question title in with the word "Japan" because a new site feature recently is banning questions with exactly the same wording. If you replaced "Japan" with "Korea" it should be fine.

Comment: Won't be a moderator thing as we'd have to manually close it.  Must be automated.  Could you paste your description and title in here so we can see the problem ourselves?

Comment: I replaced "Japan" with "South Korea" - otherwise the text is the same. I also replaced the japan tag with korea. The text I get back (automatically) is: "Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because: Sorry, this is a duplicate of Cell phones in Japan"

Comment: I want to ask it for you but I also want you to get the rep for it! Why don't you try asking it in completely new wording rather than copying and pasting? They probably do a check for percentage of exactly same text as an anti-spamming measure.

Comment: Ok - I'll try that. So you think that it should be 2 separate questions?

Answer (score 6):

The aim of the duplicate check is to avoid a large number of questions that are the same, and unfortunately it can't differentiate between true duplicates and questions that are semantically different but look similar.

It makes sense to me to ask these as two separate questions, so I'm glad you were able to get this working by rephrasing one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this puzzles me too. I don't understand the fear for a multitude of duplicates. Modern Internet technology (google) enables easy organization of these so-called duplicates. As a person living in one country and working in another I can confirm that asking about phones in one country are not duplicate to the other. Maybe there should be a button: "Ask the same question for country Z". ;)